# .bash_history is missing

Tags: command-line

Cant find .bash_history file in my home directory. Where is it?

```
echo $HISTFILE
```

says

```
/home/iam/.bash_history
```

But there is no such file.

Comment: Whats the output of `[[ -e "$HISTFILE" ]] && echo 'OK' || echo 'Not OK'` ?

Answer (score 2):

This file is hidden. Press Ctrl+H in nautilus and you will see hidden files.

Comment: Or if you use a terminal and `ls`, add the `-A` flag.

Comment: I know it is hidden, but it is really missing

Comment: you can check it by `ls -a | grep bash` command

Answer (score 0):

Then why don't you create it? Was it there before? There could be endless reasons why it's gone... only because that environment variable is set doesn't mean the file must be there.